# Multiple Xcode projects in single git repository?

Tags: git, xcode4, repository

I'm using Xcode 4 for Mac and iOS development. In the past, I've mainly used Perforce. I'm considering switching to git.

I'm looking for a recommendation regarding setting up my git repositories. I have two Xcode projects that use common source. Like this:

- dev/commonSource/ - source files used by project1 and project2.
- dev/project1/ - Xcode project and source. Uses source from commonSource.
- dev/project2/ - Xcode project and source. Uses source from commonSource.

Should I create three separate git repositories (for commonSource, project1 and project2). Or, should I create one git repository for the dev directory? I don't know what the best approach is. In this same situation with Perforce, I used one repository.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I would personally go the 3 different repo route. It seems more scalable if you were ever to want to start another project that uses the same common source code. Maybe one day, you would want to open source the common code. That would be super easy if its in its own repo.

Comment: Thanks. I'm leaning towards the three repo approach. This should make it easier to push/pull changes independently for project1 and project2. What worked great for Perforce maybe the wrong approach for git. Hopefully, one Xcode project can deal with source from two different git repositories. I don't know if this is an issue.